# How to run a compiled racket program from windows

Tags: racket

The program is run within drRacket by quoting the main funnction and passing any parameters. How do I do this from the command line or clicking on the .exe file? The main function is as follows:

```
(define (worm-main ct)
  (big-bang (make-wormState (init-worm INIT-WORM-SEGS START-POSN) "r" (food-create (make-posn 99999 99999)))
    [to-draw render]
    [on-key navigate]
    [on-tick move ct]
    [stop-when end-chk? final-scene]))
```

I call worm-main like this :- `(worm-main 0.2)`

Comment: Can you give us an idea of how you created and are calling your main function?

Comment: It's the worm program from "How to design programs". I just call worm-main with the clock tick rate. ie (worm-main 0.2).

Answer (score 2):

From what you wrote, it seems you created the executable from the “Create Executable” item in DrRacket’s “Racket” menu. You are calling the main definition from the **interaction area** by typing `(worm-main 0.2)`.

Your executable isn't working because you haven't added the call to the main function in the **definitions window**. Indeed, the executable just has the file that's in the  before creating the executable.

You must must add the call `(worm-main 0.2)` to the definitions window before creating the executable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can call a function within a file from terminal. Alternatively, in your program, you can add input statements and call the main function with these parameters.

You can run a racket program from terminal by changing the language to

```
#lang racket
```

For example:

```
#lang racket
(+ 3 4)
```

You can run that from command line using (name of file is test.rkt):

```
racket test.rkt
```

Also, you can create an executable from Dr.Racket by going to Racket, Create Executable...

Edit: Try copy pasting this and create an executable.

```
#lang racket/gui

(require racket/gui/base)

(define frame (new frame% [label "Example"]))

; Make a static text message in the frame
(define msg (new message% [parent frame]
                      [label "No events so far..."]))

; Make a button in the frame
(new button% [parent frame]
         [label "Click Me"]
         ; Callback procedure for a button click:
         [callback (lambda (button event)
                     (send msg set-label "Button click"))])

; Show the frame by calling its show method
(send frame show #t)
; source: https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/windowing-overview.html#%28part._.Creating_.Windows%29
```

I believe to see the effects of an executable, your program must create a new window.

Edit2:
Try compiling the racket program from the command line as explained here: https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/cmdline-tools.html

i.e.

```
raco make name-of-file.rkt
```

After that run:

```
cd compiled
racket name-of-file.zo
```

Comment: I have created and executable. However when I click on it from windows explorer nothing happens. Same thing applies when I run it from the command line. by typing the name of the .exe file.

Comment: @user1897830 See edit; I believe to see the effects of an executable, your program must create a new window.

Comment: @ssundarr Compiled racket programs do not need to open up a window to run. As user1897830 has tried to run the executable in the command line, he should be able to see what it prints to stdout.